# Open Source Flex (Flash) Visualization Projects

Tags: flash, apache-flex, open-source, visualization

I'm currently researching Flex visualization components for demoing purposes and am wondering if anyone in the community has had success building on top of any current open source projects.

I'm currently looking at [axiis](http://www.axiis.org/) but am wondering if anyone has found anything similar that worked well for building custom visualization components?  I've found some stuff hosted on Google code but haven't found anything very mature yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know some people who have used Flare for some very serious data visualization needs and have had a lot of success with it:

http://flare.prefuse.org/